# What does this set notation mean?

Tags: set

I am working on learning sets, cartesian products, cardinality, and so on. I am having trouble understanding what this notation means on my assignment, there was nothing in the notes about this.

The question is What are the first 6 elements of the set `{n | n >= 5 and n is prime}` and also 
    {What are the 5 smallest elements of the set   {n | ∃i > 0 such that n = 2i}.
I have no clue what this `n | n`notation means and also what the ' ∃ ' means

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: `{n | n >= 5 and n is prime}` denotes the set of values of `n` for which the condition `n >= 5 and n is prime` is true.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about set theory and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

The | symbol separates the variable representing the elements of the set from its constraints.
The question is asking you to find the first 6 elements of the set whose elements are described by the variable 'n' and the constraints on 'n' are that it is greater than or equal to 5, and it is prime.
So this will result in the following set : 5,7,11,13,17,19....
And the answer would be the first 6 elements of this set.